# How much autocorrelation is acceptable?

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, residuals

If I had performed a linear regression, on 180 observations of data, and there was autocorrelation, but normally distributed residuals like in the residual plot attached, are my model estimates reliable? [image]

Comment: It would depend on what you were trying to do with your regression.  What is your purpose?

Comment: It would also depend on how much deviation from the nominal properties would be tolerated by whoever has to do the accepting. I might accept a very different level of effect that someone else.

Comment: Is there a rule that measures degree of autocorrelation and how much bias it will introduce into the coefficient estimates?

Comment: Not really.  If your errors are not stationary everything goes out the window.  If your errors are stationary, then auto-correlation, in and of itself, does not necessarily imply the coefficient estimates will be biased at all, the standard errors will be, but that can be accounted for with generalized least squares.  Where you can get into trouble In a time series setting, is where an omitted variable is created by leaving  auto-regressive coefficients out of the regression.

Comment: The degree of omitted variable bias created would depend on the correlation between the left out variables (the auto-regressive lags) and those variables included in the regression, which would vary a lot between different data sets.  Higher correlation implies more bias, zero correlation implies zero bias.